# Sqlite Efficiency

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, relational-database

I took a class on python, sql, and datascience where I was taught to read or download a datafile/table off the web and store it in a sqlite database by going through the file line by line and and extracting data from columns and storing them in corresponding sqlite tables. My project did this with MTA subway usage data and so I have a database with tables such as 'Stations', 'Lines', 'Usage', 'Dates', etc. From what I learned, using relational databases like this is much faster and more efficient than flat tables. However, I still find reading the data from the database to be a very slow process. I thought maybe this just had to do with the size of the data (22 train lines, 450 stations, 1 year of usage), but i found that when I just store the data in a flat table, I can read it MUCH MUCH faster.

My question is- what am I missing? Is this normal? or is it likely have to do with my code? Can someone give an example of practical usage for relational databases?

I know my question is vague, but I'm really just looking to understand relational databases vs flat tables and less concerned with my specific project.

### **What I mean by *Flat Table***

I'm using the term Flat Table to refer to a basic simple spreadsheet-like table that has all the data on one "sheet". It is what you get when you call `df.to_sql()`

### **How I'm querying/using the database**

```
# Selecting descriptive data for a given station
# C_As are sub sections of a station and SCPS are Turnstile units
cur.execute('''
    SELECT Stations.stn_name, C_A.ca_name, SCPS.scp_num, Lines.line_name
    FROM Lines JOIN Stations JOIN Stn_Lines JOIN C_A JOIN SCPS ON
    Lines.line_id= Stn_Lines.line_id AND
    Stations.stn_id = Stn_Lines.stn_id AND
    C_A.station_id = Stations.stn_id AND
    SCPS.ca_id = C_A.ca_id
    WHERE Stations.stn_name = (?)
    ''', (name,))
stn_name = name #1
data = cur.fetchall()
```

or getting usage data:

```
cur.execute('''SELECT 
    Stations.stn_name, Dates.date, SCPS.scp_num,
    SUM(Usage.entries_reading), SUM(Usage.exits_reading)
    FROM Stations JOIN SCPS JOIN Dates JOIN Usage ON
    Stations.stn_id = Usage.stn_id AND
    SCPS.scp_id = Usage.scp_id AND
    Dates.date_id = Usage.date_id
    WHERE Stations.stn_name = (?)
    GROUP BY SCPS.scp_num, Dates.date
    ''', (self.name,))
data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns = ['STATION', 'DATE', 'SCP', 'T_ENTRIES', 'T_EXITS'])
```

### **Attempt at Explaining DB Table Structure**

Most of the tables are pretty simple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dates (
    date_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    date VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE
    );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Times (
    time_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    time VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE
    );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SCPS (
    scp_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
    scp_num VARCHAR(45),
    ca_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (scp_id, ca_id)
    );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C_A (
    ca_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ca_name VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE,
    station_id INTEGER,
    unit VARCHAR(45)
    );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stations (
    stn_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    stn_name TEXT UNIQUE
    );
```

However the complicated one is the Usage table which links all the data together:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usage (
     date_id INTEGER,
     time_id INTEGER,
     stn_id INTEGER,
     ca_id INTEGER,
     scp_id INTEGER,
     entries_reading INTEGER,
     exits_reading
    )
```

Comment: most probably your are using "left/right outer" joins - they may be pretty slow. Beside this SQLite is not an appropriate choice for big amount of data. Beside that you would need to check execution plans, which indexes are used, which ones are missing, etc., etc., etc. So IMO this question is toooo broad for SO...

Comment: Can you give an example of the query you are running, table and index definitions, and number of records in each of the involved tables ? I suspect the likely cause is lack of indices or joins which are not using the indices efficiently.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by the faster alternative: "flat table". Do you mean a disk file? A Python `list`? A Python `dict`?

Comment: thank you all for commenting, i've added to the post examples of my queries which @MaxU do include joins though I believe the default JOIN is an inner join.  I don't know if that's any faster.

Comment: @dbh I am unfamiliar with how indexes work. Looking into that now. Any advice/explanation on how to use would be greatly appreciated. Also adding examples of what my tables look like...

Comment: You really need to read introductions to database design and SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not create a table having just a single meaningful field . The way Dates and Times are implemented will just cause headache and extra work. Rather put the date /time stamp values directly on the table to which they correspond .

You could consider putting index and the station name, since it is used in lookups.

May I recommend generating a query plan and analyzing it?

Also  have a little look at https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html